# How to clear an set cookies with Apollo Server

Tags: node.js, cookies, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I recently just switched from using express with apollo server to just using apollo server since the subscriptions setup seemed more current and easier to setup. The problem I'm having now is I was saving a cookie with our refresh token for login and clearing the cookie on logout. This worked when I was using express.

```
     const token = context.req.cookies[process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_NAME!];
     context.res.status(401);
```

Since switching from express/apollo to just apollo server I don't have access to `req.cookies` even when i expose the req/res context on apollo server.

I ended up switching to this (which is hacky) to get the cookie.

```
      const header = context.req.headers.cookie
      var cookies = header.split(/[;] */).reduce(function(result: any, pairStr: any) {
        var arr = pairStr.split('=');
        if (arr.length === 2) { result[arr[0]] = arr[1]; }
        return result;
      }, {});
```

This works but now I can't figure out how to delete the cookies. With express I was doing

```
context.res.clearCookie(process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_NAME!);
```

Not sure how I can clear cookies now since res.clearCookie doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Simply send back the exact same cookie to the client with an `Expires` attribute set to some date in the past. Note that everything about the rest of the cookie has to be exactly the same, so be sure to keep all the original cookie attributes, too.

And, here's a link to the [RFC itself](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) on this topic:

> Finally, to remove a cookie, the server returns a Set-Cookie header
> with an expiration date in the past.  The server will be successful
> in removing the cookie only if the Path and the Domain attribute in
> the Set-Cookie header match the values used when the cookie was
> created.

As to how to do this, if you're using Node's `http` module, you can just use something like this (assuming you have a `response` coming from the callback passed to `http.createServer`):

```
context.response.writeHead(200, {'Set-Cookie': '<Your Cookie Here>', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
```

This is assuming that your `context` has access to that http `response` it can write to.

For the record, you can see how [Express does it here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L801) and [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/508936853a6e311099c9985d4c11a4b1b8f6af07/lib/response.js#L831) for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to specifically clear the cookies. The expiresIn cookie key does that for you. Here is the snippet which i used to set cookies in browser from apollo-server-lambda. Once the expiresIn date values has passed the current date time then the cookies wont be valid for that host/domain. You need to revoke access token for the user again or logout the user from the application

```
import { ApolloServer, AuthenticationError } from "apollo-server-lambda";
import resolvers from "./src/graphql/resolvers";
import typeDefs from "./src/graphql/types";
const { initConnection } = require("./src/database/connection");
const { validateAccessToken, hasPublicEndpoint } = require("./src/bll/user-adapter");
const { addHoursToDate } = require("./src/helpers/utility");


const corsConfig = {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3001",
        credentials: true,
        allowedHeaders: [
            "Content-Type",
            "Authorization"
        ],
    },
};

// creating the server
const server = new ApolloServer({
// passing types and resolvers to the server
typeDefs,
resolvers,
context: async ({ event, context, express }) => {
    const cookies = event.headers.Cookie;
    const accessToken = ("; " + cookies).split(`; accessToken=`).pop().split(";")[0];
    const accessLevel = ("; " + cookies).split(`; accessLevel=`).pop().split(";")[0];
    const expiresIn = ("; " + cookies).split(`; expiresIn=`).pop().split(";")[0];
    const { req, res } = express;

    const operationName = JSON.parse(event.body).operationName;

    if (await hasPublicEndpoint(operationName)) {
        console.info(operationName, " Is a public endpoint");
    } else {
        if (accessToken) {
            const jwtToken = accessToken.split(" ")[1];
            try {
                const verifiedUser = await validateAccessToken(jwtToken);
                console.log("verifiedUser", verifiedUser);
                if (verifiedUser) {
                    return {
                        userId: verifiedUser,
                    };
                } else {
                    console.log();
                    throw new AuthenticationError("Your token does not verify!");
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("error", err);
                throw new AuthenticationError("Your token does not verify!");
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        headers: event.headers,
        functionName: context.functionName,
        event,
        context,
        res,
    };
    
},
cors: corsConfig,
formatResponse: (response, requestContext) => {
    if (response.data?.authenticateUser || response.data?.revokeAccessToken) {
        // console.log(requestContext.context);
        const { access_token, user_type, access_token_generated_on, email } =
            response.data.authenticateUser || response.data.revokeAccessToken;

        const expiresIn = addHoursToDate(new Date(access_token_generated_on), 12);

        requestContext.context.res.set("set-cookie", [
            `accessToken=Bearer ${access_token}`,
            `accessLevel=${user_type}`,
            `expiresIn=${new Date(access_token_generated_on)}`,
            `erUser=${email}`,
        ]);

        
    }
    if (response.data?.logoutUser) {
        console.log("Logging out user");
    }
    return response;
},
```

});